# Dotnet Build Conditional PackageReference

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I need to run an ILRepack MSBuild task after build and have added the following target in our project file:

```xml
  <Target Name="MergeNet45" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45' and '$(RunILRepack)' == 'true'">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutputDir)" Command="$(ILRepack) /internalize /out:$(OutputDir)\$(AssemblyName).dll $(OutputDir)\$(AssemblyName).dll $(OutputDir)\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll  $(OutputDir)\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll $(OutputDir)\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll $(OutputDir)\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll $(OutputDir)\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="MergeStandard" AfterTargets="Build" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' and '$(RunILRepack)' == 'true'">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutputDir)" Command="$(ILRepack) /internalize /lib:$(NetStandardLoc) /out:$(OutputDir)\$(AssemblyName).dll $(OutputDir)\$(AssemblyName).dll $(OutputDir)\System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.dll  $(OutputDir)\Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.dll $(OutputDir)\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.dll $(OutputDir)\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging.dll $(OutputDir)\Newtonsoft.Json.dll $(OutputDir)\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll" />
  </Target>
```

Now for the unit test project, we have a few references that we need to include for cases when we didn't do the ILRepack, such as builds from Visual Studio.

For a normal build, I want to then pass `/p:RunILRepack=false` to allow me to run the unit tests, get code coverage and perform sonarqube analysis on the code.

In the unit test project, I have the following declared:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(RunILRepack)' == ''">
    <RunILRepack>false</RunILRepack>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

```xml
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(RunILRepack)' == 'false'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.2.4"  />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```

Alternate options I have tried without any success was:

```xml
      <ItemGroup Condition="'$(RunILRepack)' == 'false'">
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.2.4"  />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
      </ItemGroup>
```

and also moving the PackageReferences to a separate .proj file, and put a condition on the imports.

I have the above working as expected.

On a second pass, I want to pass `/p:RunILRepack=true` and this time it should run ILRepack and include some assembly references in our main dll and pack so we can publish the package.

Now for this second build, I will always get a build error like:

> error CS0433: The type 'RsaSecurityKey' exists in both 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' and 'Company.Namespace.AssemblName, Version=1.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>
> error CS0433: The type 'RsaSecurityKey' exists in both...
>
> error CS0433: The type 'JsonWebKey' exists in both ...

So this means that those references are imported, although it shouldn't be the case.

The only way I have thus far been able to get the project to build when passing `/p:RunILRepack=true` is to completely remove package references  listed above.

How can I include those PackageReference items so that they will only be imported when we set `/p:RunILRepack=false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving this by introducing an additional build Configuration and then changed the item group condition to be ignored on that Configuration:

```xml
  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'ReleaseILMerge'">
      <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" Version="5.2.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </When>
  </Choose>
```

This was the only thing that worked. I have no idea why using properties doesn't work. This must be a bug in either MSBuild or Nuget.

Comment: this is not a bug - in fact documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#adding-a-packagereference-condition): "at presently, only the TargetFramework variable is supported"

Comment: I thought I could cheat death but then I read: "Conditions can also be applied at the ItemGroup level and will apply to all children PackageReference elements"